# How to change the color of below link on click of it?

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, hyperlink, taglib

i have below code snippet. I am not getting how to change the color from red(FF0000) to black(any color) of below link on click of it?

```
<li>
<a class="optionsDropDown" href="javascript:showNewScreen();" >
   <span id="0" ><font color="FF0000"><fmt:message bundle="${link}" key="lnk_newScreen" /></font></span>
</a>
</li>
```

**EDIT2**

```
ul.optionsDropDown {
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid #D1D0CE;
  border-width: 0 1px 1px;
  display: none;
  left: -15px;
  list-style: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 12px;
  width: 135px;
  height: 90px;
  z-index: 9999;
}

ul.optionDropDown li {
  display: inline;
}

ul.optionsDropDown li a {
  display: inline;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0px 5px;
  font-size: 11px;
  color: #05040B;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul.optionsDropDown li a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

ul.optionsDropDown li a:visited{
  color: #000000;
}

 ul.optionsDropDown li a:active{
  color: #000000;
}

 </style>
<ul><li><a class="optionsDropDown" href="javascript:showNewScreen();" >
   <span id="0" ><font color="FF0000"><fmt:message bundle="${link}" key="lnk_newScreen" /></font>             </span>
</a>  
</li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this via CSS. Insert the following in the head of your document or anywhere before the markup you posted:

```
<style type="text/css">
    a.optionsDropDown:visited { color: #000000; }
    a.optionsDropDown:active { color: #000000; }
</style>
```

Comment: i want as soon as i click it. As per your suggestion i did        function showNewScreen() {
   <style type="text/css">
     a.optionsDropDown:visited { color: 000000; } }
 </style>

Comment: I edited the answer to include a second line ('active') which will change the link color at the time the click happens. Please note that you should not embed this markup in your Javascript; you should move it out of the `showNewScreen()` function (indeed, from the `<script>` tag altogether) into the document itself to make it functional. For example, you can place it in the `<head>` of the document, or directly before the `<li>` tag you referenced in your original post.

Comment: it does not work. On click of link  , a new pop up opens. But parent window which has link does not get refreshed. I think  we have to do it explicity  in javascript

Answer (score 1):

You should be styling with CSS, and not inline font tags.

Also, name and id should start with a-Z and not a number. The id="0" is invalid.

try:

```
<style type="text/css">
 a.optionsDropDown:link {color: #FF0000; }
 a.optionsDropDown:active {color: #000000; }
 a.optionsDropDown:visited {color: #000000; }
</style>

<li>
 <a class="optionsDropDown" href="javascript:showNewScreen();" >
  <span id="zero">
   <fmt:message bundle="${link}" key="lnk_newScreen" />
  </span>
 </a>
</li>
```